# Passing user input to function with char* parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, arguments, function-pointers

I'm new to this so I know this is probably something simple.

I have a function like this

```
void GroceryList::addRecord(char* itemName, char* itemType, char rating){
//do some code;
}
```

My problem is I am having trouble creating proper arguments to pass to the function.

```
I've tried something like
void main() {
    string itemName;
    cin >> itemName;
    string itemType;
    cin >> itemType;
    string rating;
    cin >> rating;

gradeBook.addRecord(itemName, itemType, rating);
}
```

I didn't expect it to work as the function is expecting char* but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the user input into a variable that I can pass to the function.  I've been search for literally 13 hours trying what I can find but no luck so far.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Answer (score 5):

Well, don't use `char*`.

```
void GroceryList::addRecord(const std::string& itemName, const std::string& itemType, const std::string& rating) { /* ... */ }
```

You can get `const char*` (not `char*`) from `string` with `c_str()` member function, e.g. `itemName.c_str()`, but unless you're doing interop with C libraries, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function prototype to

```
void GroceryList::addRecord(string itemName, string itemType, string rating){
//do some code;
}
```

I also recommend const correctness in your code, if you are not going to change the arguments, pass them by ref with const (for performance)

```
void GroceryList::addRecord(const string& itemName, const string& itemType, const string& rating){
//do some code;
}
```

All depends on the actual method body which you didn't describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string and then when passing just call `c_str()` on the string. For the rating you can just use a `char`.

Then calling the function looks like:

```
gl.addRecord(itemName.c_str(), itemType.c_str(), rating);
```

For this to work you'll need to change the function signature to `const char*` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::string::c_str(); that's what it's for:

```
gradeBook.addRecord(itemName.c_str(), itemType.c_str(), rating.c_str());
```

This function returns a `const char *`. However, the `addRecord` function doesn't seem to be const-correct, so you need to fix that.

Comment: Don't use char *'s if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't.  If you can modify
`GroceryList::addRecord`, change it to use `std::string const&`.  If you
can't modify it, then you have to ask the question: why does it use
`char*`?  There are two possible answers: the author didn't understand
`const`, or was too lazy to use it, and in fact doesn't modify the
pointed to strings.  In this case, something like
`const_cast<char*>( itemName.c_str() )` can be used; it's wordy, but
that's the price you pay when the code's author doesn't do his job
correctly.  The other possible answer is that the code does modify
something through the pointer.  In this case, the only solution involves
making a copy of the string into a `char[]`, and passing it.

Comment: You could pass &itemName[0]. You might need to manually null-terminate it, though.

Comment: @ymett If the called function does modify something, that would result in undefined behavior.  If the called function doesn't modify something, I would prefer the `const_cast`: it's more verbose, but it says clearly what is going on.

Comment: Why would it be undefined behaviour?

Comment: @ymett Because the standard says so:-).  In practice, I can't imagine a reasonable implementation where it would cause a problem, as long as the callee didn't go outside of the actual size, and no one did anything with the string object during the time the callee had the pointer.

Comment: The standard says that std::string s(1); *&s[0] = 'a'; is undefined behaviour?

Comment: @ymett No, but `*(&s[0] + 1)` is (at least in C++03).  The underlying memory in an `std::basic_string` is only guaranteed to be contiguous in C++11.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realise that was what you were referring to. Since C++11 requires the data be contiguous, and all known implementations do use contiguous memory, it seems reasonable to rely on it (even when targetting a C++03 compiler).